# Scrolling contents of a child component, Lightning Salesforce - Winter’19 release impact

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, release, scrolling

I have a component design as follows :-

```
Component A - (height - 100%)
    Component A1 - (height - 10%) 
    Component A2 - (height - 80%) (contents scrollable using (class="slds-scrollable_y")) 
    Component A3 - (height - 10%)
```

Contents of component A2 are thus scrollable with A1 and A3 as fixed, this was working fine before Winter’19 release.

But after release a new container div without class/id/height is getting introduced, which contains Component A.

```
<div data-aura-rendered-by="287:0">
    Component A - (height - 100%)
        Component A1 - (height - 10%) 
        Component A2 - (height - 80%) (contents scrollable using (class="slds-scrollable_y")) 
        Component A3 - (height - 10%) 
</div>
```

Due to this the heights of components in below hierarchy are not getting set as there is a parent div without height and thus the components A1 and A3 are not staying fixed and scroll is no longer limited to component A2.

Any help would be appretiated.

Comment: Depending on component A's style, this outer div should not matter.

Comment: @sfdcfox It matters if height is in %, as it then takes height as x% of its parent. But in my case as parent div do not have height, other's in hierarchy are also not able to get their heights.